# Search entire SQLite database for ID

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLiteStudio to view and test an sqlite database which means I don't have access to fts3 or fts4.

I have an id which I need to find from within the database and have no idea which of the 45 tables it belongs to. Is there a query I can run that will return the table name it belongs to?

Comment: Seeing as Primary Keys are only guaranteed to be unique for the table they are from, generally speaking no. You'd need more information than just a random PKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a solution to do this in SQLiteStudio. Note, that this does a full scan across all tables, all columns in every table (until it finds the match - then it stops), so this can be very slow. Be warned.

Here's how you do it:

Run SQLiteStudio, open "Custom SQL functions" dialog (it's the one with a blue brick icon).
Add new function, for exampe "`find`" and set its implementation language to `Tcl` (in top right corner). Paste following code as an implementation.

```
set value [string map [list "'" "''"] $0]
foreach table [db eval {select name from sqlite_master where type = "table"}] {
    set cols [list]
    foreach infoRow [db getTableInfo $table] {
        lappend cols "\[[dict get $infoRow name]\] = '$value'"
    }
    set res [db eval "SELECT rowid FROM \[$table\] WHERE [join $cols { OR }]"]
    if {[llength $res] > 0} {
        return "found in table $table in rows with following ROWID: [join $res ,\ ]"
    }
}
return "not found"
```

Use it from SQL query like this:

```
select find('your-id');
```

The function will scan table after table to find `your-id`. Once it finds a table, it will print ROWIDs of all rows that matched `your-id`. It will return something like:

```
found in table Products in rows with following ROWID: 345, 4647, 32546
```

Then you can query `Products` table using those ROWIDs:

```
select * from Products where rowid in (345, 4647, 32546);
```

If `your-id` will not be found, then the result of `find` will be: `not found`.

Answer (score 0):

Write this shell script into a file named `dbSearchString.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

searchFor="$1"
db="$2"

sqlite3 "$db" .tables | while read table; do
    output=`sqlite3 -line "$db" "select * from $table" | grep "$searchFor"`
    if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Found in ${table}:"
        echo "$output"
    fi
done
```

Then use it like this:

```
$ dbSearchString.sh "text to search for" database.db
```